# How to filter an array of objects in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am trying to filter my array in my angular 4 component. The array has a property which itself is an array too:

```
export const data = [
  {
    "number": "1",
    "lines": [
      "aaaaabbbb bbbbb ccccc ddddd",
      "aaaaabbbb bbbbb ccccc ddddd",
      "aaaaabbbb bbbbb ccccc ddddd",

    ]
  }
  ,
  {
    "number": "2",
    "lines": [
      "aaaaabbbb bbbbb ccccc ddddd",
      "aaaaabbbb bbbbb ccccc ddddd",
      "aaaaabbbb bbbbb ccccc ddddd",

    ]
  }
  ,
  {
    "number": "3",
    "lines": [
      "aaaaabbbb bbbbb ccccc ddddd",
      "aaaaabbbb bbbbb ccccc ddddd",
      "aaaaabbbb bbbbb ccccc ddddd",
    ]
  }
  ]
```

This is part of the component.html:

```
<input (keyup)="search($event.target.value)" />
<tr *ngFor="let item of filteredData">
        <td>{{item.number}}</td>
        <td>{{item.lines}}</td>
</tr>
```

This is part of the filter/search ts-code:

```
export class AppComponent {
    filteredData = data;

    search(val: any) {
            let ind = false;
            console.log(val);
            if (!val) this.filteredData = this.data;
            //this statement does not work:
            this.filteredData = this.data.filter(item=> item.lines.indexOf(val) >=0)
    }
}
```

How can I filter my data? Ignore the angularcode it is more about the filter statement.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: I updated the question. When I search for 'bbbbb' for example it does not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
this.filteredData = this.data.filter((item) => {
  return item.lines.filter((inner) => {
    return inner.includes(val);
  }).length > 0;
});
```

Or

```
for (const item of this.data) {
  for (const inner of item.lines) {
    if (inner.includes(val)) {
      return item;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Filtering based on `item.lines.indexOf(val)` is effectively saying:

> Give me only the items where at least one of the objects in `item.lines` **is equal to `val`**.

This is not the same as what you're trying to do, which is:

> Give me only the items where at least one of the objects in `item.lines` **contains `val` as a substring**.

You need to iterate over `item.lines` as well to get the intended result - something alone these lines* should work:

```
item => item.lines.includes(line => line.indexOf(val) >= 0)
```

Issues like this where you're accidentally calling a method on the array rather than its contents are usually easy to spot, since you'd get an error - this one was complicated by the fact that both [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) have a method called `indexOf`!

<sub>* pun not intended</sub>